# BufferedWriter on android always throws Exception

Tags: java, android

when I run this code always give me the Exception "2Error!!"

I need to save the website sitemap.xml into ImageData.html to extract the data later !!

```
private class Loading extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://example.com/post-sitemap.xml");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ImageData.html"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("1Error!!");
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("2Error!!");
        }return null;}
```

and I did not forget to put the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

stacktrace

> W: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /CategoriesData.html: open failed:
>   EROFS
>
> W: at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
>
> W: at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>
> W: at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
>
> W: at java.io.FileWriter.(FileWriter.java:80)
>
> W: at
>   codev.piclib.MainLoading$Loading.doInBackground(MainLoading.java:242
>
> W: at
>   codev.piclib.MainLoading$Loading.doInBackground(MainLoading.java:214
>
> W: at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>
> W: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>
> W: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>
> W: at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>
> W: at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>
> W: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>
> W: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only
>   file system)
>
> W: at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>
> W: at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
>
> W: at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
>
> W: ... 11 more

Comment: What is your target SDK version.

Comment: Which exception, the `MalformedURLException` or the `IOException` ? Which line throws it ?

Comment: You should specify different error messages for `MalformedURLException` and `IOException` to get closer to the root of the problem.

Comment: SDK 19 API and the Exception is IOException

Comment: And the line that throws it ?

Comment: i don't know !!! and the code work fine in Eclipse but it doesn't work in Android Studio !!

Comment: If you don't know, find out (and don't waste exclamation marks). F.ex. replace your `System.out...` with `e.printStackTrace()` - or remove the `catch` blocks altogether - and post the resulting stacktrace.

Comment: I spend the last week trying to solve this problem, I did not ask here until I run out of thoughts !

Comment: I don't think anybody at all suggested that you asked without trying. BTW I just noticed that from your title it looks like it's the call to `openStream()` that throws the `IOException`. If that is correct, you do know what line throws the exception, and you also have the stacktrace, so its "Caused by" section should help to find out why the exception occurs.

Comment: It seems the line that throws the `IOException` is `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("CategoriesData.html"));`

Comment: In that case it's not the line with the `openStream()` call; if so please consider fixing your title. However if the offending line is the one you just mentioned it looks like your code is unable to write files, maybe due to missing write permissions; you should also care about where that file is attempted to be created, chances are it's in the Eclipse folder, which might be under the "programs" folder which might require permission.  But `IOException` can be caused by many different things and without seeing the full stacktrace I don't think many people will want to spend time their guessing.

Comment: I added the stacktrace !!

Comment: And it has the hint from which in my opinion you need to start your investigation: _... Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (**Read-only file system**)_.

Comment: If you believe you have given the right permissions for your code to write on the file system but you still get the "Read-only file system"-related `IOException` you can place the following line somewhere in your code to know in which folder your file is attempted to be created: `System.out.println(new java.io.File("test.txt").getAbsolutePath());` .

Comment: aha,  that give me `/test.txt` in the root folder ! how can I change it ???

Comment: OK, it looks like you tackled a Java programming task much above your current Java expertise level. However, since it looks like we are close to solving the problem: If you want to create your file in the `/abc/def/` folder just change `new FileWriter("ImageData.html")` into `new FileWriter("/abc/def/ImageData.html")`.

Comment: Thank you SantiBailors , all problem that I have not because my expertise level But because I'm new on dealing whit Android ^_^ .